# Animated gif to avi on linux

Tags: video, ffmpeg, gif, animated-gif

Is there any way to convert an animated gif to a video format (e.g. `.avi`) on Linux?

I have already tried

```
ffmpeg -i thegif.gif thevideo.avi
```

but all I get is the first image of the video.

Comment: ffmpeg -i foo.gif foo.mkv works with current ffmpeg, and even works right with variable framerate animated gifs.  With mkv output, you get a variable frame rate mkv.  With mp4 output, it bumps up the fps as high as needed, and then duplicates frames as needed to have things display when appropriate.  e.g. a gif with some 25fps and some 10 fps made a 50fps mp4, with 2x dups and 5x dup frames depending on which part.  Storing duplicate frames doesn't take much space at all, IDK if they're even in the h.264 stream or just mp4 container.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I can suggest combination of imagemagick and ffmpeg

do this to extract each frame as png/jpeg

```
$magick> convert 'images.gif[0]' image.png
```

Do this to convert images to movie sequence

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -i image%d.jpg video.mpg
```

More help on commands

http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php

http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/19-ffmpeg-commands-for-all-needs

http://electron.mit.edu/~gsteele/ffmpeg/

Comment: If your gif has transperance you have to add -coalesce like this: convert -coalesce download.gif some%05d.png

Comment: -1, because your first command doesn’t work. But NordicMainframe’s command works.

Comment: This loses the frame rate info from the input gif.  current ffmpeg now handles animated gif input directly.

Answer (score 46):

ffmpeg's gif input doesn't work too well. It's usually easier to unpack the gif frames with convert (from ImageMagick) and process these with ffmpeg:

```
convert some.gif some%05d.png  
ffmpeg -i some%05d.png some.avi  
rm some*.png
```

Comment: Thanks I was searching for your first command line : `convert some.gif some%05d.png`

Comment: If some frames are broken because they only show difference with the base frame, use `-coalesce` option to `convert`.

Comment: when using `-coalesce` you may need to delete the first frame because it has not the same format as others (`PseudoClass` instead of `DirectClass`). It may exist a method to convert it...

Comment: This doesn't take into account the timing information for each frame. All frames will be displayed with the same frame rate.

Answer (score 9):

If you like to have a certain framerate as input because the resulting video is to fast or to slow

```
ffmpeg -r 'xx' -i some%05d.png some.avi
```

where xx is the input framerate.

Answer (score 3):

If you dont want temporary files, you can try mencoder:

```
mencoder myfile.gif -mf fps=25 -o myfile.avi -ovc lavc -lavcopts vcodec=mpeg4
```

Answer (score 0):

If you like to have a loop as output

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -t x -i some%05d.png some.avi
```

where x is the time the video should run in seconds.

[Source](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20video%20slideshow%20from%20images)