# GIF to AVI with windows Animate Control

Tags: delphi, winapi, avi, graphic

I was trying to convert a GIF image (Ajax waiting like):

[image: waiting GIF...]

to AVI that will be used with TAnimate control (win32 animation control).

I have tried a few tools, but the problem is that the output AVI is either not suitable for the Animation control or not transparent.

Notes:

- I don't use windows XP Themes manifest (D5).
  the Common Avi's are transparent even if my program is not themed.
- Using the GIF itself to show animation is not an option.

Do you know any tool that can help me with this conversion?

**EDIT:**

I have tried using [ImageMagic](http://www.imagemagick.org) with [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3212821/animated-gif-to-avi-on-linux). but I can't seem to set `ffmpeg` to encode to `msrle`.

Comment: I'm glad with rendering each frame by my own from `TImageList` without any dependency on `TAnimate` (and I'm using Ajax load animation very often :) The problems with conversion software is probably caused because `TAnimate` don't know any of the DivX or such codecs.

Comment: @TLama, sorry but this is not an option for me :)

Comment: What codec are you using or intending to use for the .avi?

Comment: Here are the specifications for the AVI file format you may use with `TAnimate` (for those who are c# or c++ here :). From [`the documentation`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE2/en/Animation_Control): _The files you use must be either uncompressed AVI files or AVI clips compressed using run-length encoding (RLE)_

Comment: @TLama The MSDN version is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761884(v=vs.85).aspx It says the same thing and so I expect kobik just needs to configure the tools to use RLE codec

Comment: @David, exactly; most (or maybe all) of the conversion tools should have the raw AVI format (uncompressed) or the RLE codec compression available to configure. Unfortunately my favorite one can't do the conversion into the video formats.

Comment: I have already tried using `ImageMagic` with `ffmpeg` as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3212821/animated-gif-to-avi-on-linux). but I can't seem to set `ffmpeg` to encode to `msrle` :/

Comment: I've used Jasc Animation Shop for this in the past, but it seems Corel no longer offers it.

Comment: @Mark, I loved the old Jasc Software stuff; they've had really user friendly tools ;) But back to the question; I've went deeper to the animation control and it seems all you need is to create an AVI file (uncompressed or compressed using run length encoding) with **the color you want to be transparent on the top left pixel of the first frame** of your video clip. It's documented in the animation control styles [`here`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761886%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: In Delphi, this style is represented as [`TAnimate.Transparent`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/XE2/en/ComCtrls.TAnimate.Transparent), so keep it set to True (what you most probably have) and try to render the video where the top left pixel of the first frame will be set to the color you want to be the transparent. Anyway, there is no animation transparency supported by animation control except this "workaround". And if you said you've been able to render the AVI file supported by this control but it was not transparent then do it this way; just modify the first frame's image ;)

Comment: @Mark Ransom, I knew that program rings a bell soon as I read `Jasc`... found it [here](https://rs171tl3.rapidshare.com/#!download|171tl6|81197608|janishop311.rar|10979|R~4A0095FF0E73EC35753950CE8A422244|0|0). tested quite a few GIFS. it works like a charm! please post your comment as answer :)

Comment: @kobik, so the animation control does support alpha channel ? I guess you've rendered your video file as the uncompressed AVI format (it supports the 24-bit bitmaps) what RLE format doesn't but I'm wondering that [`ACM_OPEN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761897%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) can resolve it. If so, then the `ACS_TRANSPARENT` style [`documentation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761886%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is wrong. Even animations in `Shell32.dll` has solid background (first frame's left top pixel), that's why I'm asking. Thanks ;)

Comment: @TLama, the information about animation control is not conclusive. I've been all over it's documentation already and gave up. I believe that when using comctrl version 6+ it actually supports blending (vista, win7 animations looks like they have "alpha channel"). how it's done internally I do not know. Jasc Animation works perfectly for me (I used 8 bpp uncompressed AVI format),

Comment: @kobik, about the alpha support with new versions of `Comctl32` makes sense somehow, I'll test it tomorrow and optionally add a comments to the documentation. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Jasc Animation Shop is able to directly read an animated GIF and write out a compressed AVI. This is an old program that appears to be no longer offered by Corel (who acquired Jasc), but you may still be able to find the free trial version for example.

Answer (score 3):

You could try [the TGIFImage component](http://www.torry.net/vcl/graphics/gif/teokgifimg.zip) (written for Delphi 5), which claims not only to support Animated GIFs, but also Transparency, **as well as a means of converting a GIF to an AVI** (and vice-versa).

Whether it does all that or not I cannot say as I haven't personally tested it. Like TLama mentioned in the OP comments above, I use my own means of playing each frame in an animated fashion (only mine uses a RES file and a TImage, where each frame is stored as a PNG for full semi-transparency support).

Comment: as I mentioned, I don't want to use a GIF component. and I really don't want to end up writing my own tool to convert GIF frames into a RLE video :)

Comment: What I'm saying is that the zip package linked claims to come with a tool to convert between GIF and AVI.

Comment: I doubled checked. no such tool, or demo that involves converting to AVI.

Comment: @kobik fair enough. I was just going on the description provided.

Comment: I have actually found Gif2Avi demo project on my PC at home! (as part of the GifImage component demo files, you can also download the full package from Torry.net). it creates the AVI files which are basically MENT to work with a TAnimate control as part of the project, but as @Warren P suggested, they are not transparent, and a some of them are generated with corrupted frames (It uses VFW to produce AVI files).

Comment: +1 that was a really good suggestion. too bad it didn't produced transparent AVis.

Answer (score 1):

Many commercial tools  do this conversion, including Corel Photo Paint, and others. A free trial is available for Corel Photo Paint, which comes included in the Corel Draw package. (Warning: It's huge, and expensive.)  I don't think the transparency will be solved any more by corel photo paint's conversion than by anybody else.

Typing some words into Google, also reveals that [DSPack](http://code.google.com/p/dspack/) from ProgDigy might help you.

The last time I did this, I abandoned the attempt to convert GIF transparency into AVI-with-transparency, because no AVI-encoding tool that I could find would preserve transparency.  Thus the solution of leaving it as a gif, and putting a new control into your app (as LaKraven suggests) may be superior in the end, to fighting it.

Comment: I think the transparency works like with Bitmaps, based on the top-left, or bottom-left color (which is usually Fuchsia. I just wonder how MS is creating the 'AVI' resources in the shell32.dll...

Comment: I believe you are right, but as this is a "developer/win32 convention", most production graphics tools do not support it.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using GDIPlus native image renderer which can easily handle animated GIFs as well as many other image types, including multi-frame TIFFs (no MNG so far). I was able to find an example component which animates TImage instance:

http://www.progdigy.com/forums/viewtopic.php?p=13156

Please note I am aware that you are looking for a solution to AVI transparency, this is just an alternative way of presenting user with a "progress", which seems to be more lightweight (no dependency on windows media playback facilities) and flexible (such animation controller can be used on any image).