# FFMPEG PHP - Converting gif to mpeg

Tags: php, ffmpeg, gif, file-conversion, mpeg

I'd like to create a simple script that converts gifs to mpegs using FFMPEG PHP. The script works when using FFMPEG in terminal. When I use a similar script using FFMEG PHP and host it on my domain, the script converts the gif to an mpeg, but only converts one frame of it. This is strange because the FFMPEG line of code that is responsible for the conversion is essentially the same line used previously in terminal. I've made sure that my web host (cirtex) has FFMPEG installed in their server. Also, I made sure to edit my php.ini file for FFMPEG use.

The script I created consists of two parts - uploader.php and uploader_02.php.

uploader.php is a simple submit form, where the user uploads and submits a gif.

uploader_02.php receives the gif and copies it over to another directory on the server. Then, the script applies the FFMPEG conversion to the saved gif.

Here's are the lines of php that are responsible for the conversion:

```
<?php
// ffmpeg
$ffmpeg = "/usr/bin/ffmpeg";
$videoFile = "test_videos/" . $name;
$output = "test_videos/instagram.mpg";
$cmd = "$ffmpeg -i $videoFile -vb 5M -y $output";
exec($cmd);   
?>
```

For some reason, only one frame of the gif is converted into mpeg format. Not sure what is causing this problem.

Any information regarding this issue will help out a lot.

Answer (score 0):

According to people online the best way to accomplish this task is to convert the gif into a series of images using imagemagic then put it back together using FFMPEG

```
exec('convert test.gif test%05d.jpg');
exec('ffmpeg -r 5 -i test%05d.jpg -y -an test.mpg');
```

Here is anther question that relates to this one [Animated gif to avi on linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3212821/animated-gif-to-avi-on-linux/3212958#3212958)

Timing between frames would be the issue that I could see arising from this though.